# Foliage recording/library recommendation?

Tags: library, wind, street

I am noticing a huge gap in my library when it comes to foliage. Mainly nice lush, dense, deciduous leaves. I some good go to recordings that are working for now, but I really want to create a huge surround space where you can hear a few different types of trees from different areas in the 5.0 sound field.

If there are any recordings out the without the wind (wind noise) element that would be amazing. I realize this might be a tall order, given the nature of the event.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out Frank's set?  I like to record where I can, but his is a pretty comprehensive starting point if you need a jump-start on variety.  As far as recording goes, more brittle types of leaves work best I find - palm trees (and other such stalky things like corn fields), and a set of brittle winter maple tree leaves I recorded at my family's house are my favorite go-to's when I need a hearty, pleasant leaf rustle which don't sound white-noisy or washy.

Comment: Thanks, @Stavrosound! I will definitely check out that library when I get a free moment.  I have some dry brittle things that have that individual leaf sound, but I am look for something more thick and meaty that can still contain the individual leaf element before it turns to white noise. I will let you know what I end up with!